# I would like to display products belonging to a sub-category on the sub-category page

Tags: php, magento, navigation, content-management-system, magento-1.7

I am using Magento CE1.7 and I am newish to php and Magento, I would like to see products from a sub-category displayed on the sub-category page, at the moment all I have is a left side bar with categories/sub-categories/ products. I'm pretty sure the function I am looking to implement was already in place and a extension install has broken it.  The category is populated with the products in "admin/catalog/manage categories"

Category "Display settings"

Display Mode : Products only

CMS Block    : Please select a block

Is Anchor    : No

"Custom Design" settings: all default values

I tried to create a static block "landing page" using a [tutorial](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-how-to-add-a-category-landing-page/#comment-877456538) which I think is what I am requesting but alas it didn't work, which makes me think did the extension install really break something.  In the tut page in the comments a user suggested that line 2 of the code needs to change to work with CE1.7 but they didn't suggest the replacement code

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_categories->count() ?>

<div>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category-            >getId()));
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>

<div>
<?php $_img = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl() ?>
<?php if($_img): ?>
<div>
<a href=”<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($_category);?>”>
<img src=”<?php echo $_img?>” title=”<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>”/>
</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div>
<a href=”<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>” title=”<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>”>
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please makes Is Anchor : Yes

Comment: I done this and it still didn't work, I also cleared cache before reloading the page.